# jupyter notebook - Why `tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden`?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tornado, nvidia-isaac

I'm trying to run [Isaac Sim in jupyter notebook](https://docs.omniverse.nvidia.com/isaacsim/latest/advanced_tutorials/tutorial_advanced_jupyter.html), but it worked before, and now it's broken. So I think this error is more general than only there.

When I start
`jupyter notebook --MappingKernelManager.default_kernel_name="Isaac Sim Python 3" $@ || error_exit`
I get the following output.

It looks ok at the start, but then, after printing the links "To access the server in the browser", it starts spamming the same tornado error (very quickly, on millisecond scale), while incrementing the number in `403 GET /api/kernels?1711376170026`

The browser opens fine, and I can run the kernel there.
These errors not always happen! I don't know why they happen. One time I can run the command and everything is fine; another time I repeat the same initial conditions - and can't get rid of the errors..

1. It's impossible to get the links "To access the server in the browser" because they disappear from the terminal so quickly due to the flood of tornado errors below.
2. I'm worried I broke something on my system..

What could be the reason?

I have Ubuntu 22.04 with 2 users.

Versions:

```bash
pip list | grep jupyter
jupyter                   1.0.0
jupyter_client            8.6.1
jupyter-console           6.6.3
jupyter_core              5.7.2
jupyter-events            0.10.0
jupyter-lsp               2.2.4
jupyter_server            2.13.0
jupyter_server_terminals  0.5.3
jupyterlab                4.1.5
jupyterlab_pygments       0.3.0
jupyterlab_server         2.25.4
jupyterlab_widgets        3.0.10
```

```
...
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:09.880 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:09.882 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:09.884 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:09.886 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:09.983 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:09.990 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:09.991 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:09.991 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:09.992 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:09.992 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/share/jupyter/lab
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:09.992 LabApp] Extension Manager is 'pypi'.
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:10.005 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:10.006 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:10.006 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:10.006 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 2.13.0 is running at:
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:10.006 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/tree?token=edcc07d729a5c440b43516a522f672b070f2a2475979068f
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:10.006 ServerApp]     http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=edcc07d729a5c440b43516a522f672b070f2a2475979068f
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:10.006 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2024-03-25 15:16:10.022 ServerApp] 
    
    
    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/fokow/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-32327-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/tree?token=edcc07d729a5c440b43516a522f672b070f2a2475979068f
        http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=edcc07d729a5c440b43516a522f672b070f2a2475979068f
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.029 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.030 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs?1711376170025 (@127.0.0.1) 1.80ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.030 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.030 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1711376170026 (@127.0.0.1) 2.07ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.030 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.030 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1711376170026 (@127.0.0.1) 2.29ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.031 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.031 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/sessions?1711376170027 (@127.0.0.1) 2.49ms referer=None
[I 2024-03-25 15:16:10.033 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed server(s): bash-language-server, dockerfile-language-server-nodejs, javascript-typescript-langserver, jedi-language-server, julia-language-server, pyright, python-language-server, python-lsp-server, r-languageserver, sql-language-server, texlab, typescript-language-server, unified-language-server, vscode-css-languageserver-bin, vscode-html-languageserver-bin, vscode-json-languageserver-bin, yaml-language-server
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.085 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.086 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs?1711376170082 (@127.0.0.1) 0.96ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.086 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.086 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1711376170083 (@127.0.0.1) 1.03ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.086 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.086 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1711376170083 (@127.0.0.1) 1.15ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.086 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.086 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/sessions?1711376170084 (@127.0.0.1) 1.28ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.087 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.087 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs?1711376170030 (@127.0.0.1) 0.31ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.129 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.129 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs?1711376170086 (@127.0.0.1) 0.71ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.129 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.129 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/sessions?1711376170127 (@127.0.0.1) 0.79ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.130 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.130 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs?1711376170125 (@127.0.0.1) 0.44ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.130 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.130 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1711376170125 (@127.0.0.1) 0.60ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.130 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.130 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1711376170126 (@127.0.0.1) 0.77ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.174 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 15:16:10.174 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs?1711376170130 (@127.0.0.1) 1.03ms referer=None
...
```

---

In cases when the jupyter kernel starts up fine (in the terminal), as soon as I select it in the VSCode jupyter notebook I get the errors shown below:

```
    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/fokow/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-38628-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8889/tree?token=1e37772639f31b6da788887ddccaea2742d10c9ec9438f3c
        http://127.0.0.1:8889/tree?token=1e37772639f31b6da788887ddccaea2742d10c9ec9438f3c
[I 2024-03-25 16:39:07.596 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed server(s): bash-language-server, dockerfile-language-server-nodejs, javascript-typescript-langserver, jedi-language-server, julia-language-server, pyright, python-language-server, python-lsp-server, r-languageserver, sql-language-server, texlab, typescript-language-server, unified-language-server, vscode-css-languageserver-bin, vscode-html-languageserver-bin, vscode-json-languageserver-bin, yaml-language-server
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:26.840 ServerApp] 404 GET /hub/api (@127.0.0.1) 6.47ms referer=None
[I 2024-03-25 16:39:26.843 JupyterNotebookApp] 302 GET /tree? (@127.0.0.1) 0.23ms
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:27.513 ServerApp] 404 GET /hub/api (@127.0.0.1) 0.68ms referer=None
[I 2024-03-25 16:39:27.515 JupyterNotebookApp] 302 GET /tree? (@127.0.0.1) 0.24ms
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.740 ServerApp] 404 GET /hub/api (@127.0.0.1) 0.83ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.740 ServerApp] 404 GET /hub/api (@127.0.0.1) 1.06ms referer=None
[I 2024-03-25 16:39:32.752 JupyterNotebookApp] 302 GET /tree? (@127.0.0.1) 0.30ms
[I 2024-03-25 16:39:32.753 JupyterNotebookApp] 302 GET /tree? (@127.0.0.1) 0.36ms
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.763 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.763 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs?1711381172753 (@127.0.0.1) 1.95ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.763 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.763 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1711381172754 (@127.0.0.1) 2.15ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.763 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.764 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs?1711381172754 (@127.0.0.1) 2.28ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.764 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.764 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1711381172755 (@127.0.0.1) 2.39ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.764 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.764 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1711381172757 (@127.0.0.1) 2.50ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.764 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.764 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/sessions?1711381172758 (@127.0.0.1) 2.62ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.764 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.765 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels?1711381172758 (@127.0.0.1) 2.77ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.765 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.765 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/sessions?1711381172759 (@127.0.0.1) 2.92ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.766 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.766 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs?1711381172763 (@127.0.0.1) 0.33ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.766 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/exts/omni.isaac.core_archive/pip_prebundle/tornado/web.py", line 3196, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/home/fokow/.local/share/ov/pkg/isaac_sim-2023.1.1/kit/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 782, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
[W 2024-03-25 16:39:32.767 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernelspecs?1711381172764 (@127.0.0.1) 0.30ms referer=None
```

I would appreciate any help!
(I posted this question [on the forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-tornado-web-httperror-http-403-forbidden-please-help/24775) too)